# "Have a sit" or "Take a sit"

Tags: grammar

Please have a sit.
Please take a sit.

What the right word to use when asking someone to sit down. Or is it have a seat?

Comment: You might be asked to "take a seat" or "have a seat", vs standing.  "Take a sit" (not to be confused with "take a shit") would be a *very* informal suggestion that you "take a load off" and rest for awhile in a chair.

Answer (score 2):

Have works.  Take works.  Even sit works.  Grammatically.

Idiomatically, I'm jumping up and down screaming "It's seat! Not sit!".

But yeah, your grammar is fine.  Sigh.

> **sit**
>
> ---
>
> verb
>
> 1. adopt or be in a position in which one's weight is supported by one's buttocks rather than one's feet and one's back is upright.
>
> "you'd better sit down"
>
> synonyms:  take a seat, seat oneself, be seated, perch, ensconce oneself, plump oneself, flop; informal take the load/weight off one's feet, plunk oneself, take a load off
>
> "here, sit on the comfy chair"
>
> 2. (of a legislature, committee, court of law, etc.) be engaged in its business.
>
> "Congress continued sitting until March 16"
>
> synonyms:  be in session, meet, be convened
>
> "the committee sits on Saturday"
>
> ---
>
> noun
>
> 1. a period of sitting.
>
> "a sit in the shade"
>
> 2. archaic
>
> the way in which an item of clothing fits someone.
>
> "the sit of her gown"
>
> [google: sit definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=sit&oq=sit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65l3j69i59&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=sit+definition)

Typically native English speakers greatly prefer take/have a seat (hence my jumping up and down). "Take a sit" is a common idiomatic mistake made by non-native English speakers. Idioms are often the hardest and last English concept English language learners master. Unlike grammar, idioms don't have a structure, logic, or pattern. A sentence or phrase simply is or isn't an idiom. It's like the difference between an article of clothing and a fashionable article of clothing.

Comment: I won't outright contradict you, but the definitions of "sit" that I have heard say that it is a verb, not a noun.  Wouldn't that make "Have a sit" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @zondo if `sit` were indeed only a verb that would be true.  Now excuse me while I take a nap.

Comment: I see, but does it make sense to say "Have a period of sitting"?  Absolutely not!  It also doesn't make sense to say "Have a sit."

Comment: @zondo Sigh, it absolutely makes sense to say, "have a period of sitting".  I know exactly what you're saying.  There is no grammar issue or ambiguity.  But it makes you sound like you're not a native English speaker.  It is simply not idiomatic.  Idioms are not constructs of grammar.  They are habits we share.  Conflating to two serves no good purpose.  Can I get back to my nap?

Comment: Not until you explain in your answer why using "sit" here would make you sound like a non-native.

Comment: @zondo 1 because typically native English speakers greatly prefer take/have a seat (hence my jumping up and down).  2 because it's a common idiomatic mistake made by non-native English speakers.  Idioms are often the hardest and last English concept English language learners master.  Unlike grammar idioms don't have a structure, logic, or pattern.  A sentence or phrase simply is or isn't an idiom.  It's like the difference between an article of clothing and a fashionable article of clothing.  Have I satisfied your demands?

Comment: Not really, but I won't keep you from your nap.

Comment: @zondo I've updated the answer.  Is that more satisfying?

Comment: Much better.  Just one more thing: there should be a comma after "Unlike grammar".  It's an introductory element that is, in a way, parenthetical.

Comment: @zondo, ah good catch.  Corrected.